# Forbidden access to custom files

Tags: .htaccess, security

I have files which contain important settings(MySQL password etc...), and jQuery scripts. I don't want them to be accessed(over link, eg. link.com/scripts/jquery_script.js). I made something but that code don't work. Code is in .htaccess file. .htaccess file is in root. I put echo in settings.php file, and I can see it.

```
<files scripts/settings.php>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</files>
```

Comment: One of the basic principles of application security in this area is that you should _whitelist_ things not _blacklist_ things, so that creative attacks don't surprise you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Files` directive doesn't take full path.

Use this directive in `/scripts/.htaccess` (create it if it doesn't exist):

```
<files settings.php>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</files>
```

Comment: Thanks! How I can redict user to page with warning message? How I can protect all files inside scripts folder?
I protected .js file but then browser can't load file.

Comment: You cannot simply block access to all the files inside `scripts` folder. Those scripts will be needed by your own pages also right?

Comment: In that case rewrite rule shouldn't block all the files inside `scripts` as there is no reliable way of doing it except by using a weak check based on `HTTP_REFERER`. There were many questions on this site related to blocking access to files available under `DocumentRoot`